# Spark saving RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] to text file got strange result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to save the userFeature of a [MatrixFactorizationModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel) to textFile, which according to the doc is a RDD of type [(Int, Array[Double])]. So I just called

```
model.userFeature.saveAsTextFile("feature")
```

However, the results I got are something like:

```
(1,[D@4b7707f1)
(5,[D@513e9aca)
(9,[D@7d09bcab)
(13,[D@31058458)
(17,[D@2a5df2a7)
(21,[D@5372efd7)
(25,[D@59d1c59a)
(29,[D@53ee5e25)
(33,[D@498f5a34)
(37,[D@4f9967eb)
(41,[D@5560afb)
(45,[D@2dc7f659)
(49,[D@b46fcc)
(53,[D@38098dd1)
(57,[D@77090fb5)
(61,[D@64769e18)
```

What I am expecting is something like:

```
(1, [1.1, 2.3, 0.4, ...])
(2, [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, ...])
...
```

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `saveAsTextFile` is to use the `toString` method. So, for an `Array`, this is merely the `hashcode`. You have two options if you stick with `saveAsTextFile`:

```
.mapValues(x=>/*TURN ARRAY DATA INTO A STRING*/).saveAsTextFile...
```

or you can use `map` to wrap the data in a custom object with a custom `toString`, or in this case a `List` and its `toString` might work

```
.mapValues(_.toList).saveAsTextFile
```